# How to create a new Mongo Database programatically?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to create a new database programatically, kind'a one database per client.

and using this:

```
public void CreateNewClientDatabase(Client client)
{
    var connectionString = Util.GetClientDatabaseConnectionString(client.DatabaseName);
    var mongoClient = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient(connectionString);
    var server = mongoClient.GetServer();

    var db = server.GetDatabase(client.DatabaseName);
    db.CreateCollection("DatabaseCreated");
}
```

The Error I'm getting on `CreateCollection` is that I do not have the correct credentials, even though that in the connection string, my credentails are correct.

The `Exception` reads as:

```
Invalid credentials for database 'client_database_name'.
```

and the `InnerException` as:

```
{"Command 'authenticate' failed: auth fails (response: { \"errmsg\" : \"auth fails\", \"ok\" : 0.0 })"}
```

The `connectionString` ends up being this:

```
mongodb://admin_user:admin_pwd@linus.mongohq.com:10042/client_database_name
```

What am I **missing**?

---

*P.S.* Using [version 1.7 of MongoDB Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Release%20Notes/Release%20Notes%20v1.7.md)

Comment: when downvoting, please mention the *why* as well, it's always good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno ... to do this on a shared service like MongoHQ, you will need to use their API to create new databases programmatically. Docs for the API are located at: http://support.mongohq.com.